# Why after onClick my hook is failing to update the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have defined a constant to use UseState Hook in ReactJS by:

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("")
```

Using the inputValue for my form in a way:

```
<form
      data-testid="form"
      onSubmit={e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setLogFilters({
          queryText: inputValue
 });
      }}
    >
```

I am able to input string in my form using the snippet below:

```
<Input
          name="input1"
          type="text"
          onChange={e => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
/>
```

I now have a button which onclick should clear the string input in the form:

```
<Button
        onClick={() => {
          setInputValue("");
}}
>
```

But the form retains the original string and the state is not set to null string. What is wrong? why is the hook not able to update the state?

Comment: because you are missing the value prop in your input

Comment: @MuhammadHaseeb Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your input field does not have the `value` attribute, it should be like below:

```
<Input
    name="input1"
    type="text"
    value={inputValue}
    onChange={e => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

As mention by @Corentin when you have any input field and you want its value to get change when you write something, you need to have a state for that, just like you have a state with name `inputValue`
you need to bind this state with your input through `value` prop i.e

```
<Input
//This will change your input when your state will be updated
   value = {inputValue} 
   name="input1"
   type="text"
   onChange={e => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
/>
```

Now, the value will get change when you will set your `inputValue` state.

Answer (score 1):

For change the value of an input with hooks, you've to initialize your state like "value" in your input.

Example :

```js
function onClick () {
  setYourState('Blabla')
}

<input placeholder='Enter blabla' value={yourState} onChange={(e) => setYourState(e.target.value)}></input>
```